# how can i do this using highcharts, superposition two series share with yAixs

Tags: highcharts

i want to do a chart like below:

- red bar's  xAxis share with blue line's yAxis datas
- red bar's yAxis using top scale,
- blue line's xAxis using bottom scale.

[image]

Comment: Connect with HighCharts support, why here?

Comment: To get a help here please post the minimum working code you have tried and the problem you are facing

Comment: @anuragal Highcharts support also works here.

Comment: @Sebastian This is really not good to support questions which have no code and no signs of even any attempt to writing the code. We are not doing any good to them

Comment: @anuragal, I don't think so, sometimes just an image is enough - like in this case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the wanted result you will need to use two `xAxis` and two `yAxis` - each for one series type and redefined your line data, because the `bar` series inverts the axes.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/482vc9np/

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      x: 49.9,
      y: 0
    }, {
      x: 71.5,
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: 106.4,
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: 129.2,
      y: 3
    }, {
      x: 144.0,
      y: 4
    }],
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    yAxis: 1,
    xAxis: 1,
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0],
  }]
```